# Android Studio 0.2.7 Project view doesn't show my project

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just updated Android Studio to 0.2.7 and my Project view (Alt+1) has gone strange.

[image]

That's all I get showing up there. I've tried restarting the IDE but it's still the same.

Anyone got any ideas what's happened?

EDIT: I've reverted to a Backup of my project from a few days ago and just copied in my java and res folder, and it seems to be working fine, but I'm still curious as to what happened in my original project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a new project and copied in the files.

This seems to be the "go to" fix for and Android Studio projects after it updates for me :p.